# Build Matrix of Comparisons in SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a question on going about a decently complicated SQL query. (I am using sql server) In my database, I have a set of Classes, and a set of Skills that those classes have (in a many-to-many relationship).

**I want to build a query that builds a matrix comparison** (similar to that in [How to create a matrix with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443070/how-to-create-a-matrix-with-sql)) **But without hardcoding each column, if possible.**
I am hoping to compare the amount of overlap for each class pair, by:

```
overlap = (Skills_Both_Classes_Have / Total_Skills) * 100
```

**My main issue is how to find the overlap of each pair of classes in a way I can modify/display.**

formatting for class table:

```
|ClassID |   ClassName |
------------------------
|1       |    Class1   |
|2       |    Class2   |
|3       |    Class3   |
```

formatting for skill table:

```
|SkillID |   SkillName |
------------------------
|1       |    Skill1   |
|2       |    Skill2   |
|3       |    Skill3   |
```

formatting for median table:

```
|ClassID |SkillID|
------------------
|1       |   1   |
|1       |   2   |
|1       |   3   |
|2       |   2   |
|2       |   4   |
|2       |   5   |
|3       |   1   |
|3       |   2   |
|3       |   5   |
```

example output:

```
       |Class1 |Class2 |Class3 | 
--------------------------------
Class1 |  100  |  033  |  066  |
Class2 |  033  |  100  |  066  |
Class3 |  066  |  066  |  100  |
```

I have been playing with pivot and the like,but am having trouble wrapping my head around the best way of implementing this in SQL.

In any other language, I would use a couple for each loops, and send the output into an array, but that doesn't seem like a very good solution in SQL. This isn't for an assignment or anything, just for my own personal curiosity.

Comment: Try to get the results in this format first: `ClassID1, ClassID2, CommonSkillCount, TotalSkills`.  Pivot right before the end but only if you really have to (since as the number of ClassIDs change, the number of columns returned will need to dynamically change).

Comment: @David M : Is that `Class VS Class` pivot or you want `Skill vs Class` pivot ? If it is same as already shown, this should help :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059865/retrieve-rows-as-columns-in-sqlserver-2008/17060280#17060280

Comment: @tommy_o That's the part I'm having trouble with, the formatting isn't as important as a query to get the "CommonSkillCount" in a way I can display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write up a query that gets what I want, but isn't exactly as easy to read as I would like.

```
--Builds a list of all combinations of classes
SELECT [ClassID], [ClassName] INTO #classnames FROM [Glad1].[dbo].[Classes] 
SELECT a.classname AS Class1, a.ClassID AS Class1ID, b.classname AS Class2, b.ClassID AS    Class2ID INTO #combos 
FROM #classnames a cross join #classnames b
SELECT Classes.ClassName,COUNT(*) AS SkillCount INTO #skillcounts FROM [Glad1].[dbo].[ClassSkills]
RIGHT JOIN [Glad1].[dbo].[Classes]
ON ClassSkills.ClassID=Classes.ClassID
GROUP BY ClassName


--Finds the percent overlap for each class combination
SELECT ClassOne, ClassTwo,CAST(ROUND(((SharedSkills * 2.0) / (sc1.skillCount + sc2.SkillCount) * 100.0),0) AS DECIMAL(8,0)) 
AS PercentOverlap INTO #percentoverlaps FROM
(SELECT cn1.ClassName AS ClassOne, cn2.ClassName AS ClassTwo, SharedSkills FROM #classnames cn1 JOIN
(SELECT Class1ID, Class2ID, Count(Class1Skills.[SkillID]) AS SharedSkills FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT [Class1ID],[SkillID] FROM [Glad1].[dbo].[ClassSkills] 
JOIN #combos ON #combos.Class1ID = ClassSkills.ClassID) Class1Skills
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT [Class2ID], [SkillID] FROM [Glad1].[dbo].[ClassSkills] 
JOIN #combos ON #combos.Class2ID = ClassSkills.ClassID) CLass2Skills
ON Class1Skills.[SkillID] = Class2Skills.[SkillID]
Group by Class1ID, CLass2ID
) AllSharedSkills
ON cn1.ClassID = Class1ID
JOIN #classnames cn2
ON cn2.ClassID = Class2ID) Named
JOIN #skillcounts sc1
ON sc1.ClassName = ClassOne
JOIN #skillcounts sc2
ON sc2.ClassName = ClassTwo

--Dynamically builds the columns to turn the results into a matrix of percent overlap
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.ClassTwo) 
            FROM #percentoverlaps c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ClassOne, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select ClassOne, ClassTwo, PercentOverlap
                from #percentoverlaps
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(PercentOverlap)
                for ClassTwo in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)



--cleans up temp tables
DROP TABLE #classnames
DROP TABLE #combos
DROP TABLE #skillcounts
DROP TABLE #percentoverlaps
```