# Creating a similarity matrix based on data stored in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, matrix, similarity

I have the following table in mysql:

```
Page; keywordId  
page1; 1  
page1; 3  
page1; 4  
page2; 4  
page3; 1  
page3; 3  
page3; 4  
page3; 5
```

I would like to create a similarity matrix containing values for each page based on their keywords like shown below. The more keywords are shared between pages, the higher the number in the matrix.

```
      page1   page2   page3  
page1   -       1       3  
page2   1       -       1  
page3   3       1       -
```

While searching for an answer, I found this [entry on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957230/build-matrix-of-comparisons-in-sql-server) that deals with almost the same problem. However, the code is pretty dense and I could not reproduce it in order to solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have only three pages, or is the number variable?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I have a about 300 pages right now, but this will change in the future. So, I guess the number is variable.

Comment: Then you really do want to get the result as a bunch of pairs as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "SQL-like" solution to what you want would look at pairs and have a separate row for each pair:

```
select ft1.page as page1, ft2.page as page2, count(*) as similarity
from followingtable ft1 join
     followingtable ft2
     on ft1.keywordid = ft2.keywordid and ft1.page <> ft2.page
group by ft1.page, ft2.page;
```

Pivoting this if you know the exact pages isn't hard.  Pivoting this for a variable number of pages is tricky in SQL and requires using a prepared statement.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding it right, but the code looks to me as if I would have to create a pair for each combination. So for 300 pages it would be 9000 pairs?

Comment: How about, if there are not only 300 pages, but ~40,000 pages? Because I'm dealing with such a big similarity matrix. Do you have any ideas? If I'm using the 'pair for each combination' approach, the search is really slow.

Comment: @joko . . . You probably just need an index if a search is too slow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks, that did the trick. Sometimes to solution is so easy :)